# FastCGI cache and WordPress, is the cache skip for querystrings really needed?

Tags: wordpress, cache, fastcgi

I'm just making a few test on FastCGI cache and I see that the suggested .conf have this directive:

```
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

This will bypass the cache for every request containing a querystring.
The problem is that all facebook links have a querystring inside, as AMP pages have ?amp=1, so is this directive really useful? is it safe to disable it?

Thanks!

Regards.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Where is that suggested configuration, and what is the environment for that suggested configuration?

Comment: It's on every Nginx WordPress installation guide:
Easyengine official: https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/single-site/fastcgi-cache-with-purging/
Nginx official: https://www.nginx.com/blog/9-tips-for-improving-wordpress-performance-with-nginx/